# How do I prevent chrome from sometimes displaying form data in the URL

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, url, http-post, forms

One of the pages on the website I am working on involves a contact form which makes use of jQuery validation before submitting it to the server.

My issue here is that on some occasions when clicking the review button, Chrome will display the form data in the URL. This is something I would like to avoid. I have tested this on Firefox and IE but the behaviour is only observed on Chrome.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Navigate to the following http://doualatees.com/shop/checkout/order/
2. Click the review order button without filling any of the fields.
3. Validation messages will appear under each field
4. Refresh the page and repeat the process 3 or 4 times
5. Observe the address bar in Chrome.
6. Try this in IE 11 and Firefox 54 - form data is not displayed

[image: Chrome displays form data in url]

Here is an extract from my html code

```
<form id="tcheckout-form" class="nml-padding">
    . . .
    <button id="tcheckout-save-btn" type="submit" class="button" title="Continue">
        <span>
            <span>Review Order</span>
        </span>
    </button>
    . . .
</form>
```

Here is an extract from my jQuery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#tcheckout-save-btn').click(function(){
        jQuery('#tcheckout-form')
            .formValidation(. . .)
            .on('success', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                . . .
                jQuery.ajax({. . .});
            });
    });
});
```

Any idea what I'm missing here? I suspect chrome is attempting to submit the form but I have no idea why.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `method="post"`. It defaults to `method="get"`, which puts the parameters in the URL.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your suggestion. I have just included method="post" like you suggested but this has now broken the field validation

Comment: You mean `.formValidation()` doesn't work? I don't know what that is, but I doubt it cares about the method attribute.

Comment: @Barmar yes I mean this causes formValidation() not to work at all in Chrome. It still works in Firefox and IE. You can test the link for yourself to see what I mean.

Comment: What plugin is `formValidation()` from?

Comment: @Barmar it is a jQuery validation plugin from a website called formvalidation.io

Comment: I don't see a documentation link there.

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: @Barmar yes there are 7 errors. These are all 404 (Not Found) errors for images which could not be loaded. The API can be found at http://formvalidation.io/api/

Comment: That's unrelated. Form validation should just be looking at the inputs, not at the form attributes. I suspect you did something else wrong when you added `method="get"` to the `<form>` element.

Comment: You're calling `e.preventDefault()` when validation succeeds. You're not calling it when validation fails, so the form gets submitted.

Comment: @Barmar I did not add method="get" to the form, I added method="post" like you suggested. That is the only thing i changed. Now that I have removed it you can see that the form works exactly as it did when i originally posted the question. You can verify this in the developer tools. I will try calling e.preventDefault() when the form fails and let you know if that helps. Thanks